# How to replace every 4th character of a string using .gsub in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, gsub

Beginner here, obviously. I need to add a sum and a string together and from the product, I have to replace every 4th character with underscore, the end product should look something like this: 160_bws_np8_1a

I think .gsub is the way, but I can find a way to format the first part in .gsub where I have to specify every 4th character.

```
total = (1..num).sum
final_output = "#{total.to_s}"  + "06bwsmnp851a"
return final_output.gsub(//, "_")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would work:

```
s = '12345678901234'
s.gsub(/(...)./, '\1_')
#=> "123_567_901_34"
```

The regex matches 3 characters (`...`) that are captured (parentheses) followed by another character (`.`). Each match is replaced by the first capture (`\1`) and a literal underscore (`_`).

Answer (score 1):

```
s = "12345678901234"
```

Here are two ways to do that. Both return

```
"123_567_901_34"
```

**Match every four-character substring and replace the match with the first three characters of the match followed by an underscore**

```
s.gsub(/.{4}/) { |s| s[0,3] << '_' }
```

**Chain the enumerator `s.gsub(/./)` to [Enumerator#with_index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index) and replace every fourth character with an underscore**

```
s.gsub(/./).with_index { |c,i| i%4 == 3 ? '_' : c }
```

See the form of [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) that takes a single argument and no block.